# Django static files (base dir moved to another folder)

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

so  what happened  is that  i put my project folder called **ecommerce** inside another folder called **ecommerce_project**  and now all the modifications i did in my css files are not showing only the previous styles are showing (before i moved **ecommerce** to **ecommerce_project**)

this is my settings :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_in_env')]
VENV_PATH = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(VENV_PATH, 'static_root')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(VENV_PATH, 'media_root')
```

how do i fix that ??

thank you

Comment: are you run collectstatic command

Comment: @Pavankumar no is that important ??

Comment: just try once we are happy if it works

Comment: i also just tried by moving one my project but for me all styles working fine

Comment: well before i moved the folder  i  go the the terminal  and i put : cd C:\Users\NAS\Desktop\ecommerce2 then python manage.py runserver  but after i moved the folder  the path changes so i  must do : cd C:\Users\NAS\Desktop\ecommerce project\ecommerce2 then runserver so   i think that is the problem

Comment: are you moving all files inside main project or you moving whole project

Comment: @Pavankumar i am moving the hole project inside another folder

Comment: ok it seems no problem in code just hard refresh your browser or open it in another browser that's what i no

Comment: @Pavankumar its working on  FireFox but not on google chrome                                             on firefox: http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/custom.css :/* your styles go here */

/* products page */

       
#gb{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: green;

}                                                                                                                                                                                                on chrome :http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/custom.css: /* your styles go here */        there  is no update

Comment: it works now but i had to delete the cookies and the history  browser that's weird :)